# Obtain video height from Silverlight Media Player Framework

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I use the Smf.CodePlex.com framework. How can I obtain the actual video size from a progressive download stream (Windows Phone)

I tried:

```
    var item = TvPlayer.CurrentPlaylistItem;                        
    var videoHeight = item.VideoHeight;             
    var videoWidth = item.VideoWidth;
```

As well as

```
    var videoHeight = TvPlayer.VideoHeight;             
    var videoWidth = TvPlayer.VideoWidth;
```

Both return NaN. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. You have to get a reference to the progressive download plugin (via the event handler)

```
    void TvPlayer_MediaPluginRegistered(object sender, CustomEventArgs<Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.IMediaPlugin> e)
    {
        IMediaPlugin a = e.Value;
        if (a.GetType() == typeof(ProgressiveMediaPlugin))
            _progressivePlugin = e.Value;
    }
```

And on the plugin the NaturalVideoSize is found.....

```
        var videoHeight = _progressivePlugin.NaturalVideoSize.Height;
        var videoWidth = _progressivePlugin.NaturalVideoSize.Width;
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know much about this Framework but i did find this:

[SMF v2 "How To" Documentation](http://smf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SMF%20v2%20%22How%20To%22%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: If this helped please vote up, or mark it as an answered question!